# xbuild error building *.sln file

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, xbuild

I need to compile c# .sln file on ubuntu.

This file is ITU gaze Tracker. They developed it base on window .net framework.

but i need to run it on ubuntu. so I tried to compile it with using xbuild.

when I type "xbuild GazeTracker.sln" I got error like below.

```
                For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}
            Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently
            For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}
            HintPath attribute not found
            For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/3.5, assembly named 'PresentationCore' not found.
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/2.0, assembly named 'PresentationCore' not found.
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/2.0, assembly named 'PresentationCore' not found.
            For searchpath {PkgConfig}
            Considered PresentationCore, but could not find in any pkg-config files.
            For searchpath {GAC}
            Considered PresentationCore, but could not find in the GAC.
            For searchpath {RawFileName}
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/GTCommons/PresentationCore' as a file, but the file does not exist
            For searchpath ../Debug/
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationCore' as a file, but the file does not exist
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationCore.exe' as a file, but the file does not exist
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationCore.dll' as a file, but the file does not exist
/usr/lib/mono/3.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'PresentationFramework' not resolved


For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}
            Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently
            For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}
            HintPath attribute not found
            For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/3.5, assembly named 'PresentationFramework' not found.
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/2.0, assembly named 'PresentationFramework' not found.
            Considered target framework dir /usr/lib/mono/2.0, assembly named 'PresentationFramework' not found.
            For searchpath {PkgConfig}
            Considered PresentationFramework, but could not find in any pkg-config files.
            For searchpath {GAC}
            Considered PresentationFramework, but could not find in the GAC.
            For searchpath {RawFileName}
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/GTCommons/PresentationFramework' as a file, but the file does not exist
            For searchpath ../Debug/
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationFramework' as a file, but the file does not exist
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationFramework.exe' as a file, but the file does not exist
            Considered '/home/sabi/Gazetracker/gazetrackinglib-code-564-trunk/Debug/PresentationFramework.dll' as a file, but the file does not exist
        Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
        No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
        Target CoreCompile:
            Tool /usr/bin/gmcs execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:full /debug+ /keyfile:GTCommons.snk /optimize+ /out:obj/Debug/GTCommons.dll Commands/AutotuneCommands.cs Commands/CalibrationCommands.cs Commands/CameraCommands.cs Commands/TrackerViewerCommands.cs Converter.cs Events/CalibrationPointEventArgs.cs Events/CalibrationResultEventArgs.cs Commands.cs Enums.cs Events/StringEventArgs.cs GTPath.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs Commands/SettingsCommands.cs Protocol.cs /target:library /define:"DEBUG;TRACE" /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Core.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Drawing.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Data.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/WindowsBase.dll /warn:4
```

how can i fix this and compile this .sln file.

or is it impossible?

plz help me

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the solution references PresentationCore / PresentationFramework - i.e. [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx)

WPF is not implemented on Mono and they have no plans to do so ([WPF - Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)).

You will need to find another implementation for the client GUI (or make one yourself!).

Comment: Is this still the case? I know see they have implemented PresentationCore, but cannot find it in my Ubuntu installation :/ http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=PresentationCore